# How does the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Preview target Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-cordova

When using the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Preview, what is the best way to also target Windows 7/desktop browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options for running and debugging your apps on Windows 7.

- Android emulator or tethered device
- iOS simulator (requires remote Mac machine)

If you want to simulate the app in your browser instead, simply choose Ripple as the deploy target (for Android and iOS). This launches the app in the Apache Ripple emulator, which runs inside the Chrome browser.